# canvas arc too pixelated

Tags: html, canvas, geometry

I try to draw an circles in canvas, I ever do it before but i found it very pixelated this time

```
var game;

function game (){

    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');



    this.initCanvas = function(){

    }

    this.draw1 = function(){
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(50, 75, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
        this.ctx.closePath();
        this.ctx.fill();
    }

    this.draw2 = function(){
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(100,75,10,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        this.ctx.closePath();
        this.ctx.stroke();
    }

    this.run = function(){
        this.initCanvas();
        this.draw1();
        this.draw2();
    }

    window.onresize = function() {
        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    };
}

game = new game();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RG6dn/6/

I don't know if this is due to the browser ( I have the same thing on chrome and firefox ) or my computer

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably were setting the width of your canvas using CSS. Altering the width of a canvas element in CSS stretches the pixels within the canvas

Eg.

`<canvas style='width:400px;height:400px'></canvas>`

Instead, you need to use the width and height properties of the canvas element itself to define how many pixels the canvas contains.

Correct way:

`<canvas width='400px' height='400px'><canvas>`

Comment: This is what helped me. Do you know why it acts like that?

Comment: Because canvas draws per pixel, so you need to define the number of pixels within the canvas itself.

CSS merely indicates the width/height in pixels, not the number of pixels actually within the canvas

Comment: It would be good to add haw to do it programmatically with javaScript (to modify it for example on page resize)

Comment: @TOPKAT This snippet will set the canvas with an id of myCanvas to the full window size when the window is resized, you may have to set the width and height outside of the event handler one time to set it initially `window.addEventListener('resize', () => { const cv = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); cv.width = window.innerWidth; cv.height = window.innerHeight; }`

Answer (score 0):

This post is not recent, but it helped me to solve my problem, but there is an error in the answer.
When we initialize the height and width of the canvas, we don't pass a string with the unit "px", but just a string with number. Like this :

```
<canvas width='400' height='400'><canvas>
```

Ajouve : in your code you make one error, after correcting the error it works

```
 var game;

 function game (){

 this.initCanvas = function(){
     this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
     this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');   
 }

 this.draw1 = function(){
     this.ctx.beginPath();
     this.ctx.arc(50, 75, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
     this.ctx.closePath();
     this.ctx.fill();
 }

 this.draw2 = function(){
     this.ctx.beginPath();
     this.ctx.arc(100,75,10,0,Math.PI*2,true);
     this.ctx.closePath();
     this.ctx.stroke();
 }
    // Here define your fonction for resizing canvas
     this.resize = function() {
     this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
     this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
 };

 this.run = function(){
     this.initCanvas();
     // Call your function here
     this.resize();
     this.draw1();
     this.draw2();
 }

}

   game = new game();

   game.run();
```