# UTF-8 in jsPDF is Working, need help Styling

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas, utf-8

I have made UTF 8 work in jsPDF to be able to print any character in a PDF from Javascript.

Arab, Chinese, Turkish it all works.

Check my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/oscoweb/fqpgcap1/2/

The thing I am doing is:

1. Write to canvas
2. Make image from canvas
3. Embed image in PDF
4. Save PDF

This works... kinda... because it is ugly!

Therefor I need help in "1. Write to canvas". The text I am writing there is hardly readable and blurry.

```
context.fillStyle = "#000000";
context.font = "Arial 14px";

context.fillText("English", 1, 20);
context.fillText("Español", 1, 30);
context.fillText("Türk", 1, 40);
context.fillText("中國", 1, 50);
```

Any help on how to write text to Canvas and keep it readable would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the low pixel ratio of the canvas.

Chack this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/

**EDIT:**

I just noticed you set the canvas size with CSS.
This might also be a problem: [canvas arc too pixelated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876234/canvas-arc-too-pixelated)

This might be helpful too:
[Poor anti-aliasing of text drawn on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262174/poor-anti-aliasing-of-text-drawn-on-canvas)

Comment: So basicly playing around with "context.scale(ratio, ratio);" should make it more readable?

Comment: @OscarBout I think so. Printed media has around 300DPIs while web has 72DPIs. This varies based on the device, see pixel ratio. I think when you scale canvas you achieve this "conversion". I have not tested, but seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Thank you I will check it out. This seems a nice playground to check things: http://jsfiddle.net/X2cKa/