# Pretty displaying SVG math Latex equation into a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

From [this link](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/09/how-to-draw-svg-on-html-5-canvas-and-why-you-might-want-to/), I would like to put a math equation (generated from `Latex` with `tex2svg` tool) into a canvas.

You can see here [this SVG formula][2] (fill color is black).

Now, I include this SVG into canvas like this :

```
<body>
<canvas id="textbox"></canvas>
<script> 
// Draw SVG formula of absolute differential
var textCanvas = document.getElementById('textbox');
var contextTextBox = textCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){ contextTextBox.drawImage(img,0,0); };
img.src = "./formula.svg";
</script>
</body>
```

You can see the result on [this link][3] (fill color of SVG is white).

The issue is that rendering is not pretty, formula is tight and blurred.

Anyone could give me clues to improve the quality of equation rendering (I don't know if it is possible to have the same quality as `MathJax` equation).

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's a basic "don't resize your canvas with CSS" issue. You're not the first coming here with this nor the last... But just search for this sentence. For a solution, set your canvas width and height via its attributes. Then use the fourth and fifth parameters of drawImage to draw your svg at the correct scale. Since it is SVG, you can even scale it up if needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [canvas arc too pixelated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876234/canvas-arc-too-pixelated)

Comment: Please re-include your original code into the question, you can also use services like [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/) to give us a live working example with both your js and the svg file.

Comment: @Kaiido: you can see an example on https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/932d8q4w/ : my issue now is that despite of the use of "box-sizing: border-box;", when I increase the padding (of "textbox" into CSS ), the size of box (i.e the canvas) increases too : that's not the behaviour I expect. If you could see where issue comes from ?

Comment: this is not the code nor the symptoms I saw yesterday no. Please include your original, buggy code as an [edit] to your question. For your other problem, I am not sure what you expect exactly, but you should ask this as a separate question since it is more related to CSS than anything else. As a recommendation, I would say style and position the container not the canvas element. Oh and did the answer you got really "solve your issue" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Math latex on canvas with subpixel rendering.

The image you provided is not of the SVG image you have linked to, so i do not know why you have the image split into 3 and squashed?

Anyways see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40074278/3877726) for a way to improve text rendering (like Latex equations) by re-rendering the image at the (physical) sub pixel level.

Note that the image must have a non opaque background colour.

The following snippet uses the core function from that answer to do the same to the SVG image.

I am using the SVG image you provided which is black on white but this method will work for all colours except for transparent pixels. If you use transparent pixels you will have to access the quality for yourself as it will depend on the background the image is drawn onto.

> **Note** may not work on outdated browsers.

```js
// the SVG image
var svg = `<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="21.371ex" height="3.676ex" style="vertical-align: -1.338ex;" viewBox="0 -1006.6 9201.2 1582.7" role="img" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-44" d="M130 622Q123 629 119 631T103 634T60 637H27V683H228Q399 682 419 682T461 676Q504 667 546 641T626 573T685 470T708 336Q708 210 634 116T442 3Q429 1 228 0H27V46H60Q102 47 111 49T130 61V622ZM593 338Q593 439 571 501T493 602Q439 637 355 637H322H294Q238 637 234 628Q231 624 231 344Q231 62 232 59Q233 49 248 48T339 46H350Q456 46 515 95Q561 133 577 191T593 338Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-76" d="M173 380Q173 405 154 405Q130 405 104 376T61 287Q60 286 59 284T58 281T56 279T53 278T49 278T41 278H27Q21 284 21 287Q21 294 29 316T53 368T97 419T160 441Q202 441 225 417T249 361Q249 344 246 335Q246 329 231 291T200 202T182 113Q182 86 187 69Q200 26 250 26Q287 26 319 60T369 139T398 222T409 277Q409 300 401 317T383 343T365 361T357 383Q357 405 376 424T417 443Q436 443 451 425T467 367Q467 340 455 284T418 159T347 40T241 -11Q177 -11 139 22Q102 54 102 117Q102 148 110 181T151 298Q173 362 173 380Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-69" d="M184 600Q184 624 203 642T247 661Q265 661 277 649T290 619Q290 596 270 577T226 557Q211 557 198 567T184 600ZM21 287Q21 295 30 318T54 369T98 420T158 442Q197 442 223 419T250 357Q250 340 236 301T196 196T154 83Q149 61 149 51Q149 26 166 26Q175 26 185 29T208 43T235 78T260 137Q263 149 265 151T282 153Q302 153 302 143Q302 135 293 112T268 61T223 11T161 -11Q129 -11 102 10T74 74Q74 91 79 106T122 220Q160 321 166 341T173 380Q173 404 156 404H154Q124 404 99 371T61 287Q60 286 59 284T58 281T56 279T53 278T49 278T41 278H27Q21 284 21 287Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-3D" d="M56 347Q56 360 70 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L390 327H72Q56 332 56 347ZM56 153Q56 168 72 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H70Q56 140 56 153Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-64" d="M376 495Q376 511 376 535T377 568Q377 613 367 624T316 637H298V660Q298 683 300 683L310 684Q320 685 339 686T376 688Q393 689 413 690T443 693T454 694H457V390Q457 84 458 81Q461 61 472 55T517 46H535V0Q533 0 459 -5T380 -11H373V44L365 37Q307 -11 235 -11Q158 -11 96 50T34 215Q34 315 97 378T244 442Q319 442 376 393V495ZM373 342Q328 405 260 405Q211 405 173 369Q146 341 139 305T131 211Q131 155 138 120T173 59Q203 26 251 26Q322 26 373 103V342Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-2212" d="M84 237T84 250T98 270H679Q694 262 694 250T679 230H98Q84 237 84 250Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-6B" d="M121 647Q121 657 125 670T137 683Q138 683 209 688T282 694Q294 694 294 686Q294 679 244 477Q194 279 194 272Q213 282 223 291Q247 309 292 354T362 415Q402 442 438 442Q468 442 485 423T503 369Q503 344 496 327T477 302T456 291T438 288Q418 288 406 299T394 328Q394 353 410 369T442 390L458 393Q446 405 434 405H430Q398 402 367 380T294 316T228 255Q230 254 243 252T267 246T293 238T320 224T342 206T359 180T365 147Q365 130 360 106T354 66Q354 26 381 26Q429 26 459 145Q461 153 479 153H483Q499 153 499 144Q499 139 496 130Q455 -11 378 -11Q333 -11 305 15T277 90Q277 108 280 121T283 145Q283 167 269 183T234 206T200 217T182 220H180Q168 178 159 139T145 81T136 44T129 20T122 7T111 -2Q98 -11 83 -11Q66 -11 57 -1T48 16Q48 26 85 176T158 471L195 616Q196 629 188 632T149 637H144Q134 637 131 637T124 640T121 647Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-393" d="M128 619Q121 626 117 628T101 631T58 634H25V680H554V676Q556 670 568 560T582 444V440H542V444Q542 445 538 478T523 545T492 598Q454 634 349 634H334Q264 634 249 633T233 621Q232 618 232 339L233 61Q240 54 245 52T270 48T333 46H360V0H348Q324 3 182 3Q51 3 36 0H25V46H58Q100 47 109 49T128 61V619Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-6A" d="M297 596Q297 627 318 644T361 661Q378 661 389 651T403 623Q403 595 384 576T340 557Q322 557 310 567T297 596ZM288 376Q288 405 262 405Q240 405 220 393T185 362T161 325T144 293L137 279Q135 278 121 278H107Q101 284 101 286T105 299Q126 348 164 391T252 441Q253 441 260 441T272 442Q296 441 316 432Q341 418 354 401T367 348V332L318 133Q267 -67 264 -75Q246 -125 194 -164T75 -204Q25 -204 7 -183T-12 -137Q-12 -110 7 -91T53 -71Q70 -71 82 -81T95 -112Q95 -148 63 -167Q69 -168 77 -168Q111 -168 139 -140T182 -74L193 -32Q204 11 219 72T251 197T278 308T289 365Q289 372 288 376Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-79" d="M21 287Q21 301 36 335T84 406T158 442Q199 442 224 419T250 355Q248 336 247 334Q247 331 231 288T198 191T182 105Q182 62 196 45T238 27Q261 27 281 38T312 61T339 94Q339 95 344 114T358 173T377 247Q415 397 419 404Q432 431 462 431Q475 431 483 424T494 412T496 403Q496 390 447 193T391 -23Q363 -106 294 -155T156 -205Q111 -205 77 -183T43 -117Q43 -95 50 -80T69 -58T89 -48T106 -45Q150 -45 150 -87Q150 -107 138 -122T115 -142T102 -147L99 -148Q101 -153 118 -160T152 -167H160Q177 -167 186 -165Q219 -156 247 -127T290 -65T313 -9T321 21L315 17Q309 13 296 6T270 -6Q250 -11 231 -11Q185 -11 150 11T104 82Q103 89 103 113Q103 170 138 262T173 379Q173 380 173 381Q173 390 173 393T169 400T158 404H154Q131 404 112 385T82 344T65 302T57 280Q55 278 41 278H27Q21 284 21 287Z"></path>
</defs>
<g stroke="currentColor" fill="black" stroke-width="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-44" x="0" y="0"></use>
<g transform="translate(764,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-76" x="0" y="0"></use>
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-69" x="686" y="-213"></use>
</g>
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-3D" x="1872" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-64" x="2928" y="0"></use>
<g transform="translate(3484,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-76" x="0" y="0"></use>
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-69" x="686" y="-213"></use>
</g>
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-2212" x="4536" y="0"></use>
<g transform="translate(5537,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-76" x="0" y="0"></use>
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-6B" x="686" y="-213"></use>
</g>
<g transform="translate(6491,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-393" x="0" y="0"></use>
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-6B" x="884" y="499"></use>
<g transform="translate(625,-304)">
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-69" x="0" y="0"></use>
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-6A" x="345" y="0"></use>
</g>
</g>
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-64" x="7753" y="0"></use>
<g transform="translate(8309,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-79" x="0" y="0"></use>
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-6A" x="706" y="583"></use>
</g>
</g>
</svg>`;


const backgroundColour = "White";

// creates a blank image with 2d context
var createImage=function(w,h){var i=document.createElement("canvas");i.width=w;i.height=h;i.ctx=i.getContext("2d");return i;}
// helper function 
function createInfoDiv(text){ var div = document.createElement("div"); div.textContent = text; return div;}

// create a canvas and add to the dom
var canvas = createImage(350,100);
canvas.style.border = "1px red solid";
var ctx = canvas.ctx;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// double canvas resolution if pixels are 2 times CSS pixel size. (might be hires or retina display)
if(devicePixelRatio === 2){
    var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;
    canvas.style.width = w + "px;"
    canvas.style.height = h + "px;"
    canvas.width = w * 2;
    canvas.height = h * 2;
}


// This function uses subpixels to render hi quality image.
// Note that the image must have a non opaque background colour
// returns the same imgData with 1st 1/3rd containing new image.
 var subPixelBitmap = function(imgData){
    var spR,spG,spB; // sub pixels
    var id,id1; // pixel indexes
    var w = imgData.width;
    var h = imgData.height;
    var d = imgData.data;
    var x,y;
    var ww = w*4;
    var ww4 = ww+4;
    for(y = 0; y < h; y+=1){
        for(x = 0; x < w; x+=3){
            var id = y*ww+x*4;
            var id1 = Math.floor(y)*ww+Math.floor(x/3)*4;
            spR = Math.sqrt(d[id + 0] * d[id + 0] * 0.2126 + d[id + 1] * d[id + 1] * 0.7152 + d[id + 2] * d[id + 2] * 0.0722);
            id += 4;
            spG = Math.sqrt(d[id + 0] * d[id + 0] * 0.2126 + d[id + 1] * d[id + 1] * 0.7152 + d[id + 2] * d[id + 2] * 0.0722);
            id += 4;
            spB = Math.sqrt(d[id + 0] * d[id + 0] * 0.2126 + d[id + 1] * d[id + 1] * 0.7152 + d[id + 2] * d[id + 2] * 0.0722);
            
            d[id1++] = spR;
            d[id1++] = spG;
            d[id1++] = spB;
            d[id1++] = 255;  // alpha always 255
        }
    }
    return imgData;
}
// clear the canvas
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

// Create the SVG image
var SVGImage = new Image(155*3,27*3);
SVGImage.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(('<?xml version="1.0"?>'+svg))

// When the image has been parsed create the hiquality subpixel rendered image.
SVGImage.onload = function(){
    try{
        var image3;
        var scale = 1;
        if(devicePixelRatio === 2){ // only for 2 as this is guessing that a Hires display is being used
            scale = 2;
        }
        image3 = createImage(this.width * scale, this.height * scale);
        var h = Math.ceil(image3.height/ 3);
        image3.ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColour;
        image3.ctx.fillRect(0,0,image3.width,image3.height);
        image3.ctx.drawImage(this,0,0,image3.width,image3.height);
        image3.ctx.drawImage(this,0,0,image3.width,image3.height+1);
        image3.ctx.drawImage(this,0,0,image3.width+0.5,image3.height);
        image3.ctx.drawImage(this,0,0,image3.width+0.5,image3.height+1);
        image3.ctx.drawImage(image3,0,0,image3.width,h)
        var dat = subPixelBitmap(image3.ctx.getImageData(0,0,image3.width,h));
        image3.width /= 3;
        image3.height = h;
        this.width /= 3;
        this.height = h;
        
        //================================================================
        // image3 now has the hi quality image
        image3.ctx.putImageData(dat,0,0);
        
        ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColour;
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        
        // draw high qual image
        ctx.font = (16 * scale) + "px arial";
        ctx.drawImage(image3,0,20 * scale);
        ctx.fillText("SVG plus (Sub pixel) render.", 5,16 * scale)
        
        // draw normal SVG on canvas
        ctx.drawImage(this,0,image3.height + 40 * scale, this.width * scale, this.height * scale);
        ctx.fillText("SVG as is rendered on canvas",5,image3.height + (20 + 16) * scale)
        document.body.appendChild(createInfoDiv("Original SVG as HTML <svg> object"));
        document.body.appendChild(this); // show original SVG
    }catch(e){
        document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>So sorry but you need to upgrade to Firefox, Edge, or Chrome!</h1>"
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @Kaiido FF could not apply a non uniform transform to MathJax SVG so just did it in pixels. Could not be bother with a high quality vertical down scale.

Comment: Better but still not as good as the default one (on non-retina) ;-) https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfSoR.png Also, it may be good to say that "outdated browsers" are all IE < Edge since they do taint the canvas when an SVG has been drawn on it. But anyway, The real problem of OP was that he didn't set his canvas size through the correct properties. You can see in his online version taht he just fixed it and it looks way better now than yesterday.